# Sentence correction in C++

Tags: c++, string, char

So i have to make a program witch does those these things with a sentence":

1. input: "This is an(5 spaces)example" ( for any punctuational mark and space)

   output :"This is an example", I have done this part, but have trouble with the other.
2. input: " This is an (5 spaces for example) ,,,,,,,,(4 spaces) example"

   I get :"This is an example" , Instead of "This is an, example.
3. If there are 1 or 2 dots , leave one dot and make the letter after it upper case.
   if there are 3 or more dots and a lower case letter after them make print 3 dots then the rest, and if the letter is upper case leave one dot. For this i have no idea what to do.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int const l=200;
int main ()
{
    char a[l];
    cin.getline(a,l);
    int d;
    d=strlen (a);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        bool p = !(a[i] == ' ' && a[i+1] == ' ');
        bool r = !(ispunct(a[i])&& ispunct(a[i+1]));
        bool t = !(a[i]==' ' && ispunct(a[i+1]));
        bool k = !(ispunct(a[i]) && a[i+1]==' ');

        if( p && r && t && k)
        {
            cout<<a[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please sort out the indentation

Comment: you don't use `string`?!

Comment: Flooding the same question over and over again!

Comment: Asking for help each and every time something doesn't work is not a solution. Friendly advice: learn to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool t=!(a[i]==' ' && ispunct(a[i+1]));
```

This erases any punctuation mark preceded by a space.

```
bool k=!(ispunct(a[i]) && a[i+1]==' ');
```

This erases any punctuation mark followed by a space.

So these two 'rules' erase all single punctuation marks if there is a space near them. Combined with the (correct) rule that erases multiple punctuation marks, you get no punctuations at all (the case 2).

As for the case 3, you need some more flags. I'd say that you need a flag that lives longer than a single loop iteration.